# Are there drinks/cocktails involving vinegar?

Tags: flavor, ingredients, cocktails

Being a huge fan of vinegar, I recently wondered if there are any actual known cocktail recipes/drinks that involve vinegar as an ingredient, preferably as a significant ingredient contributing perceivably to the drink's taste.

While there are drinks with a more spicy/hearty flavour, like *Bloody Mary*, I never heard of a cocktail involving vinegar and wonder if it would even work together with alcohol from a flavour-perspective. I could imagine the best targets to be spirits with a rather low-profile taste of their own, like vodka.

Comment: I use an occasional dash of apple cider vinegar to adjust the taste of an  overly-sweet hard cider.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**There is a whole class of drinks called [Shrubs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shrub_%28drink%29)**

Shrubs usually involve a base syrup made from vinegar and fruits and spices and then mixed with a spirit.

Shrub syrups are [available online](http://www.bonappetit.com/drinks/cocktails/article/shrubs-spritzes-swizzles) in a variety of flavors and there are plenty of recipes out there too for creating your own Shrubs at home.

My experience with and what I would define as a example Shrub would involve a shrub syrup, fresh fruit muddled in it with a spirit and then mixed, topped off with crushed ice and soda water.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do they generally have the sour taste of vinegar or does the vinegar's characterisitc taste rather vanish under sweetness? Or is it a case-by-case difference?

Comment: You get a a balance in my experience  but with all things cocktail it comes down to the recipe and proportions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are mixed drinks including vinegar or any other acidulated drink (usually called Shrub). Before adding to a drink as an ingredient, vinegar is often mixed/infused with fruits, spices, herbs.